# using rabbitmq to make database as a service

Tags: database, rabbitmq

in our architecure,each module communicate with each other using rabbitmq.
so in our situation , if a module want to access database ,first of all,it will call a rpc request using rabbitmq and  a module connecting database will return a json-like string.

my question is, is it a good idea for database access?
or is there any good idea that make database being  a service?